# JLCPCB Solder Mask Parameters for 4-Layer Impedance Controlled Stackup

Tags: impedance, stack-up

I am a bit confused by the solder mask parameters, offered by JLCPCB on their [Impedance Control](https://jlcpcb.com/impedance) page.

There you can find "*Coating Above Substrate C1*", "*Coating Above Trace C2*", "*Coating Between Traces C3*" and "*Coating Dielectric CEr*". The dielectric part is clear, but what does the different kind of coating mean? Also, this does not seem to be the same as their "*solder mask ink thickness*" as given on their [capabilities](https://jlcpcb.com/capabilities/pcb-capabilities) page.

The reason I'm asking is that I am trying to get the stackup-settings right in KiCad and that part is still unclear to me and I don't know what I'm supposed to enter as the thickness for the solder mask. Given all the other parameters for their JLC04161H-7628 Stackup, **1.2mil** brings the board thickness **1.62696 mm**, while **0.6mil** brings it to an overall thickness of **1.59648 mm** (which seems about right to me).

Maybe someone knows what they are referring to and is able to enlighten me about what is what.

Comment: Is that a typo? "12mil" is ten times larger than the biggest number given.

Comment: Oh, yes, that's a typo. It's supposed to be 0.6mil and 1.2mil. I updated the question.

Comment: So, what does it matter? Is it just a visual representation in KiCAD? Is the dimension used in calculations anywhere?  You wonder about a range of board thicknesses, but have you considered the thickness tolerance?  You ask about the C1, C2, etc.; if you absolutely must know what these are for sure, if it isn't self-evident from the descriptions, I'm afraid your best bet is to simply contact them and ask what they mean.

Answer (score 0):

JLCPCB must have created their stack-up presets and impedance calculator software using the calculations and measurements from the [Polar Instruments Impedance Calculator / Solver](https://www.polarinstruments.com/products/si/Si9000.html):

[image]

<sup>Img Src: Polar Instruments Website</sup>

The definitions on the JLCPCB website are in line with the software's:

[image]

- C1: Solder mask thickness on bare PCB (FR4 or whatever)
- C2: Solder mask thickness on copper traces
- C3: Solder mask thickness on bare FR4 but also between copper traces

The C2 is on top of the traces, so it has a direct effect on the final PCB thickness. I don't know how precise these numbers are i.e. if they "guarantee" the SM thickness given on their website, with, say, 0.1% tolerance. I wouldn't expect that precise thickness, to be honest. Regardless of entering 0.6 mils or 1.2 mils for SM thickness, which differs by 0.015 mm,  you'll probably end up with a final PCB thickness of 1.6 mm ± 1~2%.

NOTE: I don't know how much effect the SM thicknesses above have on controlled impedances.